# getaddrinfo ENOENT error in node pod inside kubernetes cluster

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, dns

I have found an issue in our project with different microservices written in Nodejs inside a K8s cluster sometimes the http calls come to an error due to a name resolution error.

For example here's an exception when a service tries to call another service called crud-service inside the same namespace:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOENT crud-service
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:109:26)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17)
```

Up to now we can say that:

- it happens sporadically, without a clear reason.
- if we try to resolve the host crud-service from the pod with the command `nslookup crud-service` works just fine.
- this problems occurs on many pods, also when we try to reach an host external to the cluster
- we don't think this problem it's related to the DNS server, in this case we should have a EAI_AGAIN error, and if we call an invalid host we should have a ENOTFOUND error

Do you have any idea to debug this problem?
Do you know how to know the reason of the ENOENT error?

Thank you

Comment: ENOENT is a Error NO ENTry error (no such file, dir ...) and seems to indicate it cannot find the socket (file) for the connection. Beyond that, I'm not sure what would cause this to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have found a solution by disabling Dynatrace on the cluster.
We are moving forward with further investigation.

Comment: Could you find what was the problem? Will appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

After investigation, it turned out that Dynatrace was the culprit. Somehow this error appeared only on Alpine-based images. Taking into account that this error was also mentioned [here](https://www.openwall.com/lists/musl/2022/07/20/1) in the context of musl:

> a call to musl's getaddrinfo appears to spuriously return ENOENT when called from a node.js application that is being monitored with the Dynatrace agent

We checked together with [@murad-samadov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12954088/murad-samadov) and suspected that Dynatrace has incompatibilities with the musl library. What we tried:

1. Switched to Debian-based images with Dynatrace being enabled
2. Disabled Dynatrace from UI on pods running on Alpine-based images by adding the rule "Do not monitor containers if Kubernetes base pod name begins with <your_base_pod_name>".

In both cases, errors disappeared